# gcc - Inheritance and templates - variable X was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, gcc

I've just been trying to port something on windows to linux. The following example compiles just fine in VS2010 and fails in g++ with `main.cpp:17:31: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope` (`g++ (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)`). Is there some workaround for accessing the base class without a tonne of casting? Is this even supported by the standard?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
public:
    int data; 
    A() {data = 42;}
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A {
};

template<typename T>
class C : public B<T> {
public:
    void print() {printf("%i\n", data);}
};

int main()
{
    C<char> c;
    c.print();
    return 0;
}
```

[*EDIT*]
The following change compiles fine in gcc.

```
    void print() {printf("%i\n", this->data);}
```

Comment: `A::data` would be fine. Not sure about standard.

Comment: Your code is not valid C++, but relies on an VS extension. Make it valid and it should compile.

Comment: @Walter by valid do you mean use `this->data` as in my edit or `A::data` or is there another more common method?

Comment: @jozxyqk Either is okay. Another option is to declare `using A::data;` inside `class B`.

Comment: @Walter thanks, I had to declare `using B<T>::data;` in `class C`, but you put me on the right track. This is quite handy to know as it fixes the problem with one line rather than having to go through pasting `this` or `A::` everywhere.